# Need beginner help with C++ syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I am busy with an assignment an I am getting an error from the compiler. I've got 4 yrs C# experience nil in C++.

I'm getting the error "Invalid conversion from nodeType,  initializing argument 1 of void linkedListType::deleteNode(const Type&) [with Type = int]' " on the line `deleteNode(current->link);`  of this function:

```
template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::deleteNodePosition(int position)
{
    nodeType<Type> *current; //pointer to traverse the list
    nodeType<Type> *trailCurrent; //pointer just before current

    if(first == NULL)    //Case 1; list is empty. 
        cerr<<"Can not delete from an empty list.\n";
    else
    {
        current = first;
        int counter = 0;

        while(current != NULL && counter <= position)
            {               
                trailCurrent = current;
                current = current->link;
                counter++;
            } // end while
        deleteNode(current->link);
    }
```

deleteNode is defined as :

```
template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
{
    .....
```

and nodeType is defined as:

```
struct nodeType
{
    Type info;
    nodeType<Type> *link;
};
```

and I am calling the offending function with this:

```
linkedListType<int> llist;
llist.insertFirst(99);
llist.insertLast(94);
llist.deleteNodePosition(2);
```

Please help?

Comment: `deleteNode()` is defined to take `const Type&` but you call it with argument `current->link` which is of type `nodeType<Type> *`.  These are incompatible types.

Comment: Thanks for editing . Didn't know about the homework tag.

Comment: No problem!  You added it in spirit when you said it was an assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the problem is pretty straightforward. This:

```
current->link
```

is defined to have type

```
nodeType<Type>*
```

But this function that you are trying to pass it to

```
void linkedListType<Type>::deleteNode(const Type& deleteItem)
```

accepts an argument of type

```
const Type&
```

Since `nodeType<Type>*` isn't at all the same thing as `const Type&`, that function can't accept that parameter.

Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to infer what you meant to do, but I would think that based on its name, the `deleteNode` function should accept a node (i.e. a `nodeType<Type>*`) rather than a piece of data contained by a node.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up moving the body of deleteNode into deleteNodePostion.

Answer (score 1):

Your deletenode method should have the following signature:

```
template<class Type>
void linkedListType<Type>::deleteNode(const nodeType<Type>& deleteItem)
```

Also, there is a problem with your while loop. current could be NULL in which case calling deletenode will be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

deleteNode takes a const Type&. You are passing it a nodeType*.

Answer (score 0):

`current->link` is of type `nodeType<Type> *`, but `deleteNode` is expecting an argument of type `Type &`.

Given the name (i.e. you're deleting a *node*) I would imagine the signature of `deleteNode` needs to change.